# Spezielles Wort für Frauen Kriegsvermisster/Kriegsverschollener nach dem Zweiten Weltkrieg

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-request

Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass es nach dem Zweiten Weltkrieg für die vielen Frauen, deren Ehemänner (vor allem in Russland) verschollen oder vermisst waren, ein spezielles Wort gegeben haben muss, wahrscheinlich sogar mehrere, regional verschiedene. Allein die große Zahl der Fälle bürgt eigentlich dafür. Leider konnte ich hier im Internet nichts finden. Kann jemand helfen?

Comment: Was macht dich da so sicher? In welchen Publikationen würde man dieses Wort finden, wenn es denn existierte?

Comment: Wenn der Vermisste für tot erklärt wurde, heißt die Hinterbliebene auch einfach Witwe.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach pragmatische argumente. sprache neigt dazu für existierende, zumal häufige, phänomene auch bezeichnungen zur verfügung zu stellen. die publikation, die ich am ehesten für auskunftsfähig einschätze sind die erinnerungen alter menschen. aus dem geschriebenen bereich evtl. heimatgeschichtliche publikationen, mit sehr viel glück geschichtsbücher.

Answer (score 3):

Für die Hinterbliebenen von im Krieg gefallenen Soldaten gibt es das Wort *Kriegerwitwe*. Dazu gibt es auch das schöne Wort *Onkelehe*.

Für die Frauen und Angehörigen von Kriegsgefangenen kenne ich keine ähnliche Bezeichnung, sofern man sie nicht einfach unter *Kriegerwitwe* einsortiert hat. Eine Spur gibt vielleicht der VdH (*Verbande der Heimkehrer, Kriegsgefangenen und Vermisstenangehörigen Deutschlands*), der schon in seinem Titel das Wort *Vermisstenangehörige* verwendet (Kriegsgefangene galten häufig lange Zeit als vermisst).

Comment: Das ist zwar eine Antwort, aber nicht auf die gestellte Frage. Hier wird ja gerade nicht nach den Witwen, sondern nach den Frauen Vermisster und Verschollener gefragt. Deine Antwort darauf ist nur, dass du keinen solchen Begriff kennst.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach "Gibt's nicht" ist doch auch eine (die) Antwort?

Comment: Wenn es so einen Begriff gegeben hätte, wäre das wohl *Kriegerstrohwitwe* gewesen. Oder vielleicht eher *Kriegsvermisstengattin*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Nicht ganz - *Strohwitwen ... Trennung von lediglich einem Tag ebenso denkbar wie ein Zeitraum von mehreren Monaten ...* (Wikipedia) - Hier geht's aber um bis zu 15 Jahre.

Comment: @Tofro  Da sehe ich keinen kategorialen Unterschied. Nur einen graduellen. Der Mann ist nicht da, ist aber auch noch nicht für tot erklärt.

Comment: @tofro: "Den Begriff gibt's nicht" ist aber etwas anderes als "Ich kenne keinen Begriff dafür". Die Nichtexistenz von etwas zu beweisen, ist zwar immer schwer, aber ohne dir zu nahe treten zu wollen, denke ich, dass das Sprachwissen einer Einzelperson hier kein hinreichender Beleg ist. Sonst hätte ja auch schon das Sprachwissen der Fragestellerin genügt, das zu belegen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Es steht dir frei, dein eigenes Sprachwissen einzubringen. Wenn du einen passenden Begriff kennst: Existenz von etwas zu beweisen, ist ja einfach ;)

Comment: Ich bringe mein Wissen ein und ich kenne den Begriff selbst ja auch nicht. Darum geht es mir hier aber nicht, ich mache dir ja keinen Vorwurf, dass du den Begriff nicht kennst. Mir geht es eher darum, dass der zweite Teil deiner Antwort den Eindruck zu erwecken geeignet ist, den Begriff gäbe es nicht, dass zugleich jedoch dafür keine Belege gegeben werden.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Wie du selbst geschrieben hast, ist es unmöglich, Belege für eine Nichtexistenz von etwas zu bringen - Diese Diskussion ist deswegen irgendwie müßig.

Comment: Auch wenn absolute Gewissheit über die Nichtexistenz des Begriffs nicht zu bekommen ist, kann man dennoch graduell verschiedene Wahrscheinlichkeit erreichen. Eine höhere Wahrscheinlichkeit für die Nichtexistenz des Begriffs wäre bspw. durch Recherche belegbar. Ein bloßes `Ich selbst kenne den Begriff nicht` steht doch eher am unteren Ende der Skala der graduellen Sicherheit dieses Wissens, oder?

Comment: Ich gebe deswegen hier -1.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann danke, das mit den strohwitwen ist ein sehr guter hinweis!